# How to embed video content from news site to iOS App?

Tags: ios, flash, uiwebview, video-streaming, flowplayer

I want to show news sites video content in my App. Either in an embedded via `UIWebView` or to open Safari an preload video, start to show it from a certain second. How can I do it? What is the basic concept?

The video url is here: http://www.atv.hu/videok/video-20141102-havas-a-palyan-1-resz-2014-11-01

And I want to show the content from 22:19 to 23:09. How can I do it? Do I violate any copyright law?

Site use a flow player lightweight technology to stream data.

[image]